# How to transform an area of pasture to a vegetable garden?

Tags: vegetables, soil, grass, soil-amendment

What is the best way to transform a 300 m<sup>2</sup> area of pasture land to a vegetable garden? I do not mean lawn, but real grassland previously cut down regularly by farmers to feed animals.

https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/habitats/grasslands/

How would you tackle this and how long does it take for soil to become appropriate for crops?

Comment: Need to have a bit more detail.  Not sure what you are asking.  What is a functional field?  Are you wanting to make a pasture for animals to eat?  Or are you looking for a way to make a once grass pasture into a vegetable garden?  If so...I've done this all by me little self quite a few times.